# Number of posts on profile gives contradictory answers for new users who have posts deleted in the VLQ queue

Tags: bug

Here is an image from the profile of a new user who had their first post deleted in the Very Low Quality queue (for being a "me too!" comment):
[image]

The information in "Top Tags" says that they've had one post, but the information in "Top Answers" claims that they haven't asked or answer any questions, which seems contradictory.

Comment: Questions are also included in the post count. Does that user have a question?

Comment: Likely just caching.  The tag stats are expensive, and as such aren't computed in real time.

Comment: @Floern No, as shown on the image, the user has no questions *or* answers (other than the answer that was deleted in the VLQ queue for being a "me too!" comment).

Comment: So that tag counts are [probably cached](http://shouldiblamecaching.com).

Comment: @Servy That seems like a distinct possibility.